# Get values of a ListBox Multiple

Tags: c#, jquery-chosen

I'm in a hard time trying to get the selecteds values of a ListBox (SelectionMode="Multiple") in the code behind using the chosen plugin. Can someone give-me a help?

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" ID="ddlObs" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DdlObsSelectedIndexChanged" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control chosen-select">
<asp:ListItem Value="">(Vazio)</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Seu texto adequou se apenas parcialmente.</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Todo texto deve ser realizado no formulário.</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Toda atividade deve respeitar nº de linhas estabelecido no enunciado.</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Seu texto adequou se parcialmente ao enunciado.</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>A atividade postada não corresponde à disciplina.</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>A atividade foi postada em branco.</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Toda atividade deve conter o nome da atividade estudada</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Outro</asp:ListItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reference `ddlObs.SelectedItems`, something like this:

```
foreach(Object item in ddlObs.SelectedItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.toString());
}
```